# how to make the line connecting the parent node to child node longer?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to draw a tree using the following code, however, the line connecting S0 and S1 is not long enough as described in the following picture, may someone help me?[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance=0.7cm, sibling distance=4.5cm}}
\tikzset{level 2/.style={level distance=0.7cm, sibling distance=4.5cm}}

\tikzset{bag/.style={text width=20em,text centered,yshift=-0.2cm}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down, -stealth]
{\node[bag]{$S_0{:}(m)$}
    child{ edge from parent node[left=0.1cm]{$$}; \node[bag]{$S_1{:}(i_1)$}
       child{ edge from parent node[right=0.1cm]{$$}; \node[bag]{$S_4{:}(s)$}
       }
    }
    child{ edge from parent node[right=0.1cm]{$$};
    \node[bag,yshift=-1.0cm]{$S_2{:}(t_1)$}
       child{ edge from parent node[left=0cm]{$$}; \node[bag]{$S_5{:}(t_1{+}t_2)$}
       }
       child{ edge from parent node[right=0cm]{$$}; \node[bag]{$S_6{:}(t_1{+}t_3)$}
       }
    }
    child{edge from parent node[right=0.1cm]{$$}; \node[bag]{$S_3{:}(t_3)$}
       child{ edge from parent node[right=0.1cm]{$$}; \node[bag]{$S_6{:}(t_1{+}t_3)$}
       }
    };
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

From the blue region you have drawn I guess you mean S0 and S2. You are placing empty nodes for the edges and then extra `\node` syntax. Converting everything into the default entries gives the expected output but I am not sure what the end product you have in mind.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance=0.7cm, sibling distance=4.5cm},
       level 2/.style={level distance=1cm, sibling distance=4.5cm},
       bag/.style={text width=20em,text centered,yshift=-0.2cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down,-stealth]
\node[bag]{$S_0{:}(m)$}
    child{node[bag]{$S_1{:}(i_1)$}
       child{
          node[bag]{$S_4{:}(s)$}
       }
    }
    child{ node[bag,yshift=-1.0cm]{$S_2{:}(t_1)$}
       child{ 
          node[bag]{$S_5{:}(t_1{+}t_2)$}
       }
       child{ node[bag]{$S_6{:}(t_1{+}t_3)$}
       }
    }
    child{ node[bag]{$S_3{:}(t_3)$}
       child{ node[bag]{$S_6{:}(t_1{+}t_3)$}
       }
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to extend the first level arrows to the nodes, then you need to decrease the node size since as it is the node width is 20em and shape border is too big compared to the contents.